# How can I identify a specific data point in tee chart and apply style

Tags: c#, teechart

I have a Points chart, I need to identify a specific data point and apply the style, below code does the styling for all the points but I need few point to be shown in Circle and few in Cross.

**Code**

```
Steema.TeeChart.Styles.Points points = new Steema.TeeChart.Styles.Points(frmApplication.DefInstance.VtChart1.Chart)
points.Pointer.Style = Steema.TeeChart.Styles.PointerStyles.Circle;
points.Add(xValue, yValue);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the GetPointerStyle event to modify the Point

```
points.Add(0, 4);
points.Add(1, 3);  //more point add etc

//connect to the GetPointerStyle event to modify specific Point Pointerstyle at runtime.
points.GetPointerStyle += new Steema.TeeChart.Styles.CustomPoint.GetPointerStyleEventHandler(point_GetPointerStyle);
}

private void point_GetPointerStyle(Steema.TeeChart.Styles.CustomPoint series, Steema.TeeChart.Styles.GetPointerStyleEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.ValueIndex == 2)
    e.Style = Steema.TeeChart.Styles.PointerStyles.Cross;
  else
    e.Style = Steema.TeeChart.Styles.PointerStyles.Circle;
}
```